# ACAGetTransmitterBulkRequestStatus. TPE1122: “WS Security Header in the message is invalid.”

Tags: xml, web-services, soap-client, irs

I can successfully send BulkRequestTransmitterService request to IRS. 
But i stuck with ACAGetTransmitterBulkRequestStatus. It faults with TPE1122: "The WS Security Header in the message is invalid".

I am using java and apache xmlsec for request generation, the same classes for BulkRequestTransmitterService and ACAGetTransmitterBulkRequestStatus but BulkRequestTransmitterService successfull and ACAGetTransmitterBulkRequestStatus failed.

I've already added InclusiveNamespaces and tuned prefixes, but still TPE1122: "The WS Security Header in the message is invalid". 
I've already asked technical support, but they are gave standard response to me 
"Check doc, check headers, etc.".

I've already readed:

[Invalid WS Security Header - IRS ACA SOAP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687024/invalid-ws-security-header-irs-aca-soap-request#)

[IRS Soap Fault - Invalid WS Security Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942628/irs-soap-fault-invalid-ws-security-header)

[Getting "WS Security Header in the message is invalid." when calling ACAGetTransmitterBulkRequestStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359953/getting-ws-security-header-in-the-message-is-invalid-when-calling-acagettrans)

[IRS ACA 1095B BulkRequestTransmitter: Invalid WS Security Header - SOAP UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560875/irs-aca-1095b-bulkrequesttransmitter-invalid-ws-security-header-soap-ui)

I have no new ideas, please tell me what i doing wrong, my request and response:

```
---[HTTP request - https://la.www4.irs.gov/airp/aca/a2a/1095BC_Status_Request_AATS2016]---
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate 
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "RequestSubmissionStatusDetail"
User-Agent: Metro/2.3 (tags/2.3-7528; 2013-04-29T19:34:10+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.8 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-8ACB711D603109F02FCD341CD1D73E7A">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#TS-E69C3A9C6891CCFE1FFECE43A0B7B5E7">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 wsse wsu"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>J/gI5JSDeM3z5gRnLV7b1cd7/kY=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#BH-D4F0B9B3093469091486C9515FDA764E">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 wsse wsu"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>KMvmV76a1jkXtTD0XPW7maTUjCs=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#ST-D4D9163B8E3EB6106D2D64BD4E155B2F">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 wsse wsu"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>zgTna1cbhsw3bMhOQyqv+Ku1OiM=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
PhQWcToQ3LO7YUaGFhMpCaaktAwpjSLKCRtMzMFfoflru4SK/+rNQOD3p8IiEqd0wXL8CDz2vnoY
oiw4utsIpMvOKeQDVyZpUAvWiwBBe8QWyUi8CPYwC3rjREUP4+BRt1cKSc/QpEhyhHCeyDAfi9A7
6CllipUVNs9VE6rPPppuMncyhLdPWeHGswkaWiXwwOH88UFkY1KFmxrnk8I+o5+M+U1MEqHPuUqF
kXz5bknLp8/MZtGRp8i/GUlvW68E7E7aL+2lXCDAnK3LZ3AkgFr/MG6vgawymkQ8i6cxiZCAeLcc
3VZY90oHYC9e+efdqdBwmnFPz3Fi5xPQ5O7ZdQ==
</ds:SignatureValue>

<ds:KeyInfo><wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STR-E68EBBF1696C5DD4AA143353323390476"><wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">REMOVED</wsse:KeyIdentifier></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><wsu:Timestamp xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="TS-E69C3A9C6891CCFE1FFECE43A0B7B5E7"><wsu:Created>2016-05-25T14:52:08.961Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2016-05-25T15:02:08.961Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security><urn:ACABusinessHeader xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="BH-D4F0B9B3093469091486C9515FDA764E"><urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>a02b754e-4f78-4c44-8c77-654b2713dd16:SYS12:REMOVED::T</urn1:UniqueTransmissionId><urn2:Timestamp>2016-05-25T14:52:03Z</urn2:Timestamp></urn:ACABusinessHeader><wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">RequestSubmissionStatusDetail</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><urn:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irstransmitterstatusrequest" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" version="1.0" wsu:Id="ST-D4D9163B8E3EB6106D2D64BD4E155B2F"><urn1:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl><urn2:ReceiptId>1095C-16-00056212</urn2:ReceiptId></urn1:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl></urn:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>--------------------

---[HTTP response - https://la.www4.irs.gov/airp/aca/a2a/1095BC_Status_Request_AATS2016 - 500]---
null: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Length: 781
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 25 May 2016 14:52:09 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: dc=dcd;Max-Age=900;Secure;Path=/;Version=1;
X-Cnection: close
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The WS Security Header in the message is invalid. Please review the transmission instructions outlined in Section 5 of the AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide located at https://www.irs.gov/for-Tax-Pros/Software-Developers/Information-Returns/Affordable-Care-Act-Information-Return-AIR-Program, correct any issues, and try again.</faultstring>
            <detail>
               <errorcode>TPE1122</errorcode>
               <uniqueTransmissionID/>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>--------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved,

IRS use different namespaces for ACABusinessHeader.

For BulkRequestTransmitterService it should be urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader

For ACAGetTransmitterBulkRequestStatus  it should be urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irstransmitterstatusrequest